# Replace Key pairs without rebooting or detaching/attaching the volumes in AWS ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want my existing ec2 instance to replace the keys and create New keys.

I don't want to reboot and detach/attach the volumes of ec2 instance. Is there any way to change the key pairs without creating the image/snapshot of the server?

Answer (score 0):

Using keypairs with SSH is a function of the operating system. It has nothing specific to do with Amazon EC2.

When you use SSH to connect to an instance, you provide a **private key**. The Linux operating system on the target computer/instance will then look in the designated user's home directory and look in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. If a matching **public key** is found in that directory, the login is permitted.

For example, if you are connecting with:

```
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@IP-ADDRESS
```

then it will look in:

```
/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Therefore, if you wish to add/replace keys for a user, simply **edit the contents** of the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file in the home directory.

See:

- [How to replace public SSH keys on your AWS EC2 instance | VentureBeat](https://venturebeat.com/2016/11/23/how-to-replace-public-ssh-keys-on-your-aws-ec2-instance/)
- [Add New User Accounts with SSH Access to an Amazon EC2 Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/)